# Using Vulkan-hpp vk::enumerateInstanceVersion() causes segfault

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, segmentation-fault, vulkan

I encountered a weird issue. I can use `vkEnumerateInstanceVersion` from `vulkan.h`, but using `vk::enumerateInstanceVersion()` from `vulkan.hpp` causes an `memory access violation` (segfault).

I use this function to create the `vk::Instance`:

```
static vk::Instance createInstance()
{
    loadVulkanGlobalFunctions();

    uint32_t version;
    vkEnumerateInstanceVersion(&version); // works fine, returns version 1.2.131
    version = vk::enumerateInstanceVersion(); // error 0xC0000005 memory access violation

    std::cout << "Supported Vulkan Version is "
              << VK_VERSION_MAJOR(version) << '.'
              << VK_VERSION_MINOR(version) << '.'
              << VK_VERSION_PATCH(version) << '\n';

    // instance creation ...
}
```

I load global Vulkan functions using the default dynamic loader:

```
static void loadVulkanGlobalFunctions()
{
    vk::DynamicLoader loader;
    auto vkGetInstanceProcAddr = loader.getProcAddress<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>("vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
    VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(vkGetInstanceProcAddr);
}
```

I `#define VULKAN_HPP_DISPATCH_LOADER_DYNAMIC 1` before `#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>` and I have `VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCH_LOADER_DYNAMIC_STORAGE` exactly once in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the `vk::DynamicLoader` object created in `loadVulkanGlobalFunctions` must have its lifetime extended, as it unloads the dynamic library in its destructor. As it is a local variable that happens when `loadVulkanGlobalFunctions` exits and the stack unwinds.
I simply changed it to this:

```
static vk::DynamicLoader createVulkanLoader()
{
    vk::DynamicLoader loader;
    auto vkGetInstanceProcAddr = loader.getProcAddress<PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr>("vkGetInstanceProcAddr");
    VULKAN_HPP_DEFAULT_DISPATCHER.init(vkGetInstanceProcAddr);
    return loader;
}
```

And assigned the result to a variable, whose lifetime is longer than of the `vkInstance`.